# need 100% div without setting a fixed height on container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link to a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9NYcn/11/ i put together with what i would like to do, but i need to do this with pure css.

```
function expand(){
    var sect = document.getElementById("sect");
    var body = document.getElementById("main");
    var panes = document.getElementById("panes");
    var newHeight = 40 + "px";
    var newHeight2 = 120 + "px";
    var topVal = 120 + "px";
    sect.style.display = "block";
    sect.style.height = newHeight;
    body.style.height = newHeight2;
    panes.style.top = topVal;
}
```

In the above function i had to set the "top" property of panes in order to get this to work. i need to get it so that the panes section will work like it currently does without using javascript to change the "top" property of "panes". When the user clicks the "expand" button the div with the class "body" will expand and not stick behind or overlap the "panes" div.

I know im doing a terrible job explaining i apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the absolute positioning of `.panes`: http://jsfiddle.net/rHTM8/

It will make it naturally flow after the middle div.

Comment: correct but the "inner-panes" div's are no longer scroll-able and i need them to be

Comment: i had to use javascript in the end but thanks anyway. i dont think that what i was attempting to do was even possible.